# Load script inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a script such as:

```
<script> document.body....make something and draw many things in the browser </script>
```

Which I'd like to execute sandboxed inside an iframe.
How can I load this piece of javascript inside the iframe?

I'm trying that which does not work:

```
document.getElementById('previewFrame').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<script language='javascript'></script>";
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't manipulated stuff via javascript on another 'site' due to security restrictions. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: And - on that note, you cant insert scripts via innerHTML - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: I'm in the same domain. The iframe is mine and starts empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name the frame and do

```
window.frames["framename"].document.write('<script>...<\/script>');
window.frames["framename"].document.close();
```